# Identification of South Indian plant

Tags: botany, species-identification

I'm from South India and I'm having quite a fuss identifying this plant. 
It has totally transparent stems, and when I break them, water squeezes out. My local friend tells me that this was used in the olden days to clean slates. It has a bit fat stem. And another thing about this plant is that when you soak it in Ink, you can see the ink travelling up it. That's why it is so transparent.

I heard that it is locally called *Mashithandu* and I searched all  over the net for it, but can't find a name except that. I'm **really sorry** I can't add a photo. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are talking about *Peperomia pellucida*. It is called  Mashithandu in Malayalam.

[image]

<sub>[Reference: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peperomia_pellucida)</sub>

You might like to go through [this](http://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/230638).

> **Description**
>
> Delicate, glabrous annual herbs; stems erect, 5-30 cm tall, ***pellucid***,
>   branched when well developed.
>
> **Global Distribution**
>
> Native of Tropical America; now Pantropical
>
> **Indian distribution**
>
> State - Kerala in all Districts

Answer (score 0):

Common names
It is known as pepper elder, silverbush, rat-ear, man-to-man, clearweed (North America); prenetaria (Puerto Rico); konsaka wiwiri (Suriname); coraçãozinho or "little heart" (Brazil); lingua de sapo, herva-de-vidro, herva-de-jaboti or herva-de-jabuti (South America), ewe rinrin (Yoruba Nigeria), corazón de hombre (Cuba).[11] In Oceania, it is called rtertiil (Belauan); podpod-lahe or potpopot (Chamorro). In the different dialects of the Philippines, it is called pansit-pansitan or ulasimang-bato (Tagalog), olasiman ihalas (Bisaya), sinaw-sinaw or tangon-tangon (Bikol), lin-linnaaw (Ilocano) and "clavo-clavo" (Chavacano). In other parts of Asia, it is known as càng cua (Vietnam);sagar bataing သဂါဗတာင် (Mon); pak krasang ผักกระสัง (Thailand); "krasang teap" ក្រសាំងទាប (Cambodia); suna kosho (Japan); rangu-rangu, ketumpangan or tumpang angin (Bahasa/Malay); sasaladahan (Sundanese); rinrin (Nigeria), "shining bush" (Trinidad and Tobago), and mashithanduമഷിത്തണ്ട്, വെള്ളത്തണ്ട് and വെള്ളപ്പച്ചില (Malayalam); diya thippili දිය තිප්පිලි (Sinhalese). In west Bengal, India the plant is locally known as "Luchi pata". In Guyana the plant is also known as "Soldier Parsley."

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. In addition, scientific names (i.e. latin binomials) are much more useful than a list of common names. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 